# JavaScript find and highlight text search button not working

Tags: javascript

I'm using the script below to find and highlight text on a page. It works perfect if you enter the text and press the enter key but the weird thing is it doesn't work if you click the Find button, unless you first click somewhere on the page first. Its like when the search box is in focus or highlighted, the Find button won't work, even though it will work in focus with the Enter key. I tried removing the focus in CSS but no luck.

```
<script type="text/javascript">   
        var TRange=null;

        function findString (str) {
         if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion)<4) return;
         var strFound;
         if (window.find) {

          // CODE FOR BROWSERS THAT SUPPORT window.find

          strFound=self.find(str);
          if (!strFound) {
           strFound=self.find(str,0,1);
           while (self.find(str,0,1)) continue;
          }
         }
         else if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft")!=-1) {

          // EXPLORER-SPECIFIC CODE

          if (TRange!=null) {
           TRange.collapse(false);
           strFound=TRange.findText(str);
           if (strFound) TRange.select();
          }
          if (TRange==null || strFound==0) {
           TRange=self.document.body.createTextRange();
           strFound=TRange.findText(str);
           if (strFound) TRange.select();
          }
         }
         else if (navigator.appName=="Opera") {
          alert ("Opera browsers not supported, sorry...")
          return;
         }
         if (!strFound) alert ("String '"+str+"' not found!")
         return;
        }
    </script>
```

This is the search form

```
<form id="f1" name="f1" action="javascript:void()" onsubmit="if(this.t1.value!=null &amp;&amp; this.t1.value!='') parent.findString(this.t1.value);return false;">
    <input type="text" id="t1" name="t1" value="text" size="20">
    <input type="submit" name="b1" value="Find">
</form>
```

I found the script at http://www.javascripter.net/faq/searchin.htm

Comment: Please tell me, what exactly you expect a submit button to do?

Comment: @Teemu the submit button finds and highlights the text you enter. It works when you press the enter key but not when you click the button. It's kinda like a javasript version of browsers built in Ctrl + F search functionality.

Comment: No, submit button sends the form to your server, and  the server sends its response back to your page ... For [starters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events).

Answer (score 2):

Replace your form code with this (added onclick method on button):

```
<form id="f1" name="f1" action="javascript:void()" onsubmit="if(this.t1.value!=null && this.t1.value!='') parent.findString(this.t1.value);return false;">
    <input type="text" id="t1" name="t1" value="text" size="20">
    <input type="submit" name="b1" value="Find" onclick="if(this.t1.value!=null && this.t1.value!='') parent.findString(this.t1.value);return false;">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks @mitch but unfortunately that doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 0):

the button works fine, just need to clean up your html and script like so ([jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k0nkL3kh/3/)):

```
<form id="f1" name="f1" action="javascript:void(0)" onsubmit="
findString(this.t1.value);return false;">

    <input type="text" id="t1" name="t1" value="text" size="20">
    <input type="submit" name="b1" value="Find">
</form>
```

and the javascript:

```
 var TRange=null;

        window.findString = function(str) {
        alert(str);
        if (parseInt(navigator.appVersion)<4) return;
         var strFound;
         if (window.find) {

          // CODE FOR BROWSERS THAT SUPPORT window.find

          strFound=self.find(str);
          if (!strFound) {
           strFound=self.find(str,0,1);
           while (self.find(str,0,1)) continue;
          }
         }
         else if (navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft")!=-1) {

          // EXPLORER-SPECIFIC CODE

          if (TRange!=null) {
           TRange.collapse(false);
           strFound=TRange.findText(str);
           if (strFound) TRange.select();
          }
          if (TRange==null || strFound==0) {
           TRange=self.document.body.createTextRange();
           strFound=TRange.findText(str);
           if (strFound) TRange.select();
          }
         }
         else if (navigator.appName=="Opera") {
          alert ("Opera browsers not supported, sorry...")
          return;
         }
         if (!strFound) alert ("String '"+str+"' not found!")
         return;
        }
```

Comment: That creates a pop up box with the text @sweaver2112

Comment: Do I just remove `alert(str);`? If so, that doesn't solve the issue @sweaver2112

Comment: the code illustrates getting the Find button to call your function correctly, which was the question. I cannot vouch for whatever goal your method is trying to do.

Comment: The goal is to find the text when clicking the Find button the same way it does when clicking on the page first or using the enter key instead, both of which worked with the original code. Unfortunately this doesn't solve that issue.